# cd on the last folder tcsh

Tags: shell, command-substitution, tcsh

trying to cd on the last directory in bash

if im trying this :

```
cd $(ls -l | tail -l)
```

it will result in :

```
Illegal variable name.
```

I'm not sure how I should do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(...)` is Korn/POSIX shell syntax. Command substitution in (t)csh is done with `` `...` ``.

In `tcsh`, you could do:

```
set dirs = (./*/); cd $dirs[$#dirs]:q
```

To `cd` into the last directory (or symlink to directory) in a lexically list of non-hidden directoties in the current directory.

That is better than:

```
cd "`ls | tail -n 1`"
```

Which wouldn't work if there were file names that contain newline characters or start with `-` (or `+` followed by digits) or if the last file in the current directory is not a directory.

Your Ksh syntax `cd $(ls | tail -1)` is even worse as it would also fail with filenames with spaces or tabs or wildcard characters.

Note that the order is lexical, where for instance `2` sorts **after** `10`. For a numeric sort, with the GNU implementation of `ls`, you can use the `-v` option (`` cd "`ls -v | tail -n 1`" ``)

With the `zsh` shell, you'd do:

```
cd ./*(/[-1])
```

Or to also consider symlinks to directories:

```
cd ./*(-/[-1])
```

To sort the files numerically:

```
cd ./*(n-/[-1])
```

Comment: many thanks ! my directory only contains numbers so it was a pretty simple case but it is always best to know a more clean way

Comment: @DrWeeny, beware that in a lexical sorting as done by `ls`, `2` comes **after** `10` for instance. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the string that you get is not the name of the directory, instead a string that contains some info about the directory like `drwxrwxr-x.  3 alessiosavi alessiosavi   4096 Sep 10 09:51 workplace-tmp` and not your target name that is `workplace-tmp`

For accomplish the work, we can run the following step:
 1. Save the last directory in a variable
 2. Check that the variabile is a dir
 3. Cd into the directory

```bsh
file=$(ls -l  | tail -n1 | awk '{print $9}') ; if [ -d "$file" ];then cd $file; else echo "$file not a directory" ; fi
```

***"Is bash, you need only 1 line"***